# WheelNav JS Css Styles

Tags: css, wheelnav.js

Im using WheelNavJS and Im trying to get at least 3 on the same page

according to..
http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/css3.html

you use the syntax

```
[class|=wheelnav-divWheel]
```

where divwheel is the ID of the wheelnav Div

my question is, since I have more than one wheel, each has a different ID (but all are in the same class)  Is there a quick method of applying the same styles to all the wheels on my page?

```
[class|=wheelnav-divWheel],[class|=wheelnav-divWheel2],[class|=wheelnav-divWheel3]
```

does seem to work n some cases (not all depending on the feature) and seems abit messy?

can i get rid of the
    [class|=

this could be really novice but I've not seen css written like that before i usually use . and #

Perhaps what im really asking is, can i change it to apply to classes rather than IDs.  Or if anyone count point me in the direction of when one would use     [class|=] instead of the usual # or. selectors?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or plunker or something demonstrating your problem?

Comment: sure.  I understand.  I just dont want to paste an answer without testing it.  If you made a jsfiddle or plunker, I could test the answer, which would save every time, including future people with the same question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, sorry, i probably havnt been very clear.  I basically just want to neaten up my css.  Im not familiar with 

    [class|=]

style of writing and Ill end up with lots of things like
[class|=wheelnav-wheel1-slice-selected],[class|=wheelnav-wheel2-slice-basic],[class|=wheelnav-wheel3-slice-basic]

which seems inefficient, if i add more wheels id have to extend that further to include a wheel4 etc.

Comment: Hi @Rooster  I think i managed to paste an incomplete comment before, apologies as it wasn't finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because every item in wheelnav has unique class name. For example: 'wheelnav-wheel1-slice-selected-0'. This ensures that all elements are allowed to be with a different style.

Basically you can apply classes just these class names based on the holder div of wheelnav.

The [[attribute|="value"]](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) selector is used to select elements with the specified attribute starting with the specified value.

So you can achieve your needs with [class|='wheelnav'] selector.

```
[class|='wheelnav'] {
    fill: #1572b6;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/fatanup/edit?html,css,output) for that.